# Why doesn't find . -delete delete current directory?

Tags: find, directory, rm

I would expect

```
find . -delete
```

to delete the current directory, but it doesn't. Why not?

Comment: Most likely because removing the current working directory would not be a good idea.

Comment: Agreed--I like the default behavior, but it is not consistent with, e.g., `find . -print`.

Comment: @AlexejMagura although I sympathize, I do not see why removing the current directory should be any different than removing an open file. The object will stay alive until a reference to it exists, and then garbage collected afterward. You can do `cd ..; rm -r dir` with another shell with quite clear semantics...

Comment: @Rmano this is true: it's just something I wouldn't do on principle: just go up a directory and then delete the current directory.  I'm not entirely sure why it's such a big deal--though I have had some misfortunes with the current directory no longer existing, such as relative paths no longer working, but you can always get out by using an absolute path--but some part of me just says that it isn't a good idea in general.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The members of `findutils` [aware of it](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?20802), it's for compatible with *BSD:

> One of the reasons that we skip deletion of "." is for compatibility
>   with *BSD, where this action originated.

The **NEWS** in findutils source code shows that they decided to keep the behavior:

> `#20802: If -delete fails, find's exit status will now be non-zero. However, find still skips trying to delete ".".`

**[UPDATE]**

Since this question become one of the hot topic, so i dive into FreeBSD source code and come out a more convincing reason.

Let's see the [find utility source code of FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/386ddae58459341ec567604707805814a2128a57/usr.bin/find/function.c):

```
int
f_delete(PLAN *plan __unused, FTSENT *entry)
{
    /* ignore these from fts */
    if (strcmp(entry->fts_accpath, ".") == 0 ||
        strcmp(entry->fts_accpath, "..") == 0)
        return 1;
...
    /* rmdir directories, unlink everything else */
    if (S_ISDIR(entry->fts_statp->st_mode)) {
        if (rmdir(entry->fts_accpath) < 0 && errno != ENOTEMPTY)
            warn("-delete: rmdir(%s)", entry->fts_path);
    } else {
        if (unlink(entry->fts_accpath) < 0)
            warn("-delete: unlink(%s)", entry->fts_path);
    }
...
```

As you can see, if it doesn't filter out dot and dot-dot, then it will reach `rmdir()` C function defined by POSIX's `unistd.h`.

Do a simple test, rmdir with dot/dot-dot argument will return -1:

```
printf("%d\n", rmdir(".."));
```

Let's take a look [how POSIX describe rmdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rmdir.html):

> If the path argument refers to a path whose final component is either
>   dot or dot-dot, rmdir() shall fail.

No reason was given why `shall fail`.

I found `rename` [explain some reaso](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html)n:

> Renaming dot or dot-dot is prohibited in order to prevent cyclical
>   file system paths.

**Cyclical file system paths** ?

I look over **The C Programming Language (2nd Edition)** and search for directory topic, surprisingly i found [the code is similar](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119194955/http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/fsize.html):

```
if(strcmp(dp->name,".") == 0 || strcmp(dp->name,"..") == 0)
    continue;
```

And the comment !

> Each directory always contains entries for itself, called ".", and its
>   parent, ".."; these must be skipped, or the program will **loop forever**.

**"loop forever"**, this is same like how `rename` describe it as **"cyclical file system paths"** above.

I slightly modify the code and to make it run in Kali Linux based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381195/1074998):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void fsize(char *);
void dirwalk(char *, void (*fcn)(char *));

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 1)
        fsize(".");
    else
        while (--argc > 0) {
            printf("start\n");
            fsize(*++argv);
        }
    return 0;
}

void fsize(char *name) {
    struct stat stbuf;
    if (stat(name, &stbuf) == -1 )  {
        fprintf(stderr, "fsize: can't access %s\n", name);
        return;
    }
    if ((stbuf.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
        dirwalk(name, fsize);
    printf("%81d %s\n", stbuf.st_size, name);
}

#define MAX_PATH 1024
void dirwalk(char *dir, void (*fcn)(char *))
{
    char name[MAX_PATH];
    struct dirent *dp;

    DIR *dfd;

    if ((dfd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: can't open %s\n", dir);
            return;
    }

    while ((dp = readdir(dfd)) != NULL) {
            sleep(1);
            printf("d_name: S%sG\n", dp->d_name);
            if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0
                            || strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0) {
                    printf("hole dot\n");
                    continue;
                    }
            if (strlen(dir)+strlen(dp->d_name)+2 > sizeof(name)) {
                    printf("mocha\n");
                    fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: name %s/%s too long\n",
                                    dir, dp->d_name);
                    }
            else {
                    printf("ice\n");
                    (*fcn)(dp->d_name);
            }
    }
    closedir(dfd);
}
```

Let's see:

```
xb@dnxb:/test/dot$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai 4096 Nov 20 04:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 xiaobai xiaobai 4096 Nov 20 04:14 ..
xb@dnxb:/test/dot$ 
xb@dnxb:/test/dot$ cc /tmp/kr/fsize.c -o /tmp/kr/a.out 
xb@dnxb:/test/dot$ /tmp/kr/a.out .                     
start
d_name: S..G
hole dot
d_name: S.G
hole dot
                                                                             4096 .
xb@dnxb:/test/dot$
```

It work correctly, now what if I comment out the `continue` instruction:

```
xb@dnxb:/test/dot$ cc /tmp/kr/fsize.c -o /tmp/kr/a.out 
xb@dnxb:/test/dot$ /tmp/kr/a.out .
start
d_name: S..G
hole dot
ice
d_name: S..G
hole dot
ice
d_name: S..G
hole dot
ice
^C
xb@dnxb:/test/dot$
```

As you can see, I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill this infinitely loop program.

The '..' directory read its first entry  '..' and loop forever.

**Conclusion:**

1. GNU `findutils` try to compatible with `find` utility in ***BSD**.
2. `find` utility in *BSD internally use `rmdir` POSIX-compliant C function which dot/dot-dot is not allow.
3. The reason of `rmdir` do not allow dot/dot-dot is prevent cyclical file system paths.
4. **The C Programming Language** written by K&R shows the example of how dot/dot-dot will lead to forever loop program.

Answer (score 16):

Because your `find` command returns `.` as result. From the info page of `rm`:

> Any attempt to remove a file whose last file name component is ‘.’ or
>   ‘..’ is rejected without any prompting, as mandated by POSIX.

So, it looks like `find` just sticks to POSIX rules in this case.

Comment: As it should: POSIX is king, plus removing the current directory could cause some very big problems depending on the parent application and what not.  Like what if the current directory were `/var/log` and you ran that as root, thinking that it'd remove all the subdirs and it removed the current directory as well?

Comment: That's a good theory, but the `man` page for `find` says: "If the removal failed, an error message is issued." Why is no error printed?

Comment: @AlexejMagura Removing the current directory works fine in general: `mkdir foo && cd foo && rmdir $(pwd)`.  It's removing `.` (or `..`) that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The rmdir system call fails with EINVAL if the last component of its argument path is `"."`. It's documented at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rmdir.html
and the rationale for the behavior is:

> The meaning of deleting pathname /dot is unclear, because the name of
>   the file (directory) in the parent directory to be removed is not
>   clear, particularly in the presence of multiple links to a directory.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `rmdir(".")` as a system call didn't work when I tried it, so no higher level tool can succeed.

You must delete the directory through its real name not its `.` alias.

Answer (score 1):

While 林果皞 and Thomas already gave good answers on this, I feel that their answers forgot to explain *why* this behaviour was implemented in the first place.

In your `find . -delete` example deleting the current directory sounds pretty logical and sane. But consider:

```
$ find . -name marti\*
./martin
./martin.jpg
[..]
```

Does deleting `.` still sound logical and sane to you?

Deleting a non-empty directory is an error – so you're unlikely to lose data with this with `find` (although you could with `rm -r`) – but your shell will have its current working directory set to a directory that no longer exist, leading to some confusing and surprising behaviour:

```
$ pwd
/home/martin/test
$ rm -r ../test 
$ touch foo
touch: cannot touch 'foo': No such file or directory
```

*Not* deleting the current directory is simply good interface design and complies with the principle of least surprise.